# property gets reset on click event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

file1.ascx :

```
<div id="bondDialog" runat="server" style="display: none;">
        <pto:BondList ID="bondList" runat="server"/>
        <div class="table_tools">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="bold" ui-button="ui-icon-cancel" Text="<%$ Resources:Label, SelectTaskDialog_lnkCancel %>" />
        &nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnSelect" runat="server" CssClass="bold" ui-button="ui-icon-accept" Text="<%$ Resources:Label, SelectTaskDialog_lnkSelect %>" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

file1.ascx.vb I have these :

```
Public Property DataSource As List(Of Model.Bond)
Private Sub gvBondDialog_DataBinding(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bondList.DataBinding
            If DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
                CType(bondList.FindControl("gvBondDialog"), GridView).DataSource = DataSource
            End If
        End Sub

Public Sub lnkBtnSelect_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lnkBtnSelect.Click
            Dim source = DataSource
        End Sub
```

The DataSource property is initialized in a parent ascx file.
In the gvBondDialog_DataBinding function I have no problem, my DataSource is set as expected.
But when I click on my select button and go in the lnkBtnSelect_CLick function then DataSource is at Nothing.
I struggle to understand why the page cycle reset the DataSource and how could I avoid that.
I thought of adding the DataSource in the viewState but the Model.Bond object is not serializable.
Is there another solution?

Thx,

Comment: Is ViewState enabled on your page?

Comment: This looks like an event in your page is resetting it, first look at using "!isPostBack" to prevent a property from being reset.